# IKImage Gesture zoom rotate

Tags: cocoa, zooming, rotation, gesture, ikimageview

In my application I use IKImageview to preview a image,and by default it supports two finger gestures like moving up,down,left,right.
Now I want to add rotate and zoom gestures to it ,does anyone has any good ideas?
Thank you very much.

does anyone know how to subclass IKImageview to support zoom gesture?

Comment: oh, I'm sorry could you tell me how to accept answers?

Comment: I didn't find any button to press to accept . I am new to stack overflow sorry again.

Comment: just left to every answer is a checkmarker. just click the one next to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figure it out.
Just subclass the `IKImageView` and add:

```
- (void)rotateWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event{
    [self setFrameCenterRotation:([self frameCenterRotation] + [event rotation])];
}
```

Problem solved!